# Couldn't resolve resource @array/example while i using it in ListPreference

Tags: android, arrays

> error :  Rendering Problems  Couldn't resolve resource @array/pref_units_options (2 similar errors not shown)  Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

I try to clean and build this project and invalidate cashes/restart and now I have no way to solve this problem.

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="@string/pref_location_label"
        android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ListPreference
        android:title="@string/pref_units_label"
        android:key="@string/pref_units_key"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_units_metric"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_units_values"
        android:entries="@array/pref_units_options" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="pref_units_options">
        <item>@string/pref_units_label_metric</item>
        <item>@string/pref_units_label_imperial</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="pref_units_values">
        <item>@string/pref_units_metric</item>
        <item>@string/pref_units_imperial</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Where is `arrays.xml` in your project?

Comment: in res/valus as normal @CommonsWare